# Android Programming: Find the database key id from listview with checkbox. To do list / grocery list

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, checkbox, onclick

I am a beginner when it comes to programming with Android/Java, and I am having trouble with what shouldn't be too difficult to accomplish. I am using code I've tried to adapt from the Google Notepad v1. I realize this version is far from complete, but it was the most stripped down to begin on.

What I am trying to do is modify the list to note include notes, but rather make it function like a to-do list, where one would add items to the list. Next to each item, there needs to be a checkbox. I'm writing the checkbox state to the database, and where I am having trouble is gathering the related id from the database for each checkbox. If I manually specify which item I want in the list it works, but I'm unable to get OnClick (setChk) to pull the id I need for the database. I am posting 4 important code files below.

I have had so many problems trying to get this to work, and at this point in programming, I'm just creating things to gain programming skills. If anyone has a functioning to-do list as I've described, I would greatly appreciate seeing a working sample code. I greatly appreciate any help!

Finished.java

---

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Finished extends ListActivity {


    public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;

    private int mNoteNumber = 1;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);




    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    fillData(); 
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        createNote();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void createNote() {
    String noteName = "Note " + mNoteNumber++;
    mDbHelper.createNote(noteName, "", "1");
    fillData();
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECK };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.CheckBox1 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);



    notes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
      public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int nCheckedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECK);
        if (columnIndex == nCheckedIndex) {
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;

          boolean bChecked = (cursor.getInt(nCheckedIndex) != 0);
          cb.setChecked(bChecked);
          return true;
        }

        return false;


        }

    });


    setListAdapter(notes);

  }

public void setChk(View view) {

    //Below is where I need help
    mDbHelper.updateChk(//insert proper number id in list to delete, "1");
    //I understand I don't want second value to be 1. It was also just a test
    //I need to work on getting the id first before anything else
    Toast.makeText(this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    fillData();

}

}
```

---

notes_row.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/text1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</TextView>

<CheckBox 
android:id="@+id/CheckBox1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:onClick="setChk"
android:text="setChk">
</CheckBox>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

notepad_list.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_notes"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

NotesDbAdapter

---

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

public class NotesDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CHECK = "check";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, body text not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;


private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}


/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
 * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
 * a -1 to indicate failure.
 * 
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note
 * @return rowId or -1 if failed
 */
public long createNote(String title, String body, String check) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, check);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the note with the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 * 
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY, KEY_CHECK}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
 * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY, KEY_CHECK}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
 * values passed in
 * 
 * @param rowId id of note to update
 * @param title value to set note title to
 * @param body value to set note body to
 * @param check 
 * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body, String check) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    args.put(KEY_CHECK, check);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

New Finished. java

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECK };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.CheckBox1 };

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    final SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);



    notes.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            int nCheckedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECK);
            if (columnIndex == nCheckedIndex) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;

                boolean bChecked = (cursor.getInt(nCheckedIndex) != 0);
                cb.setChecked(bChecked);

                //call if after setChecked so the listener isn't called there already
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int position = getListView().getPositionForView(buttonView);
                        Cursor c = notes.getCursor();
                        if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {

                            int rowid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));

                            if (isChecked) {
                                mDbHelper.updateChk(rowid, "1");


                            } else {
                                mDbHelper.updateChk(rowid, "0");

                            }


                        } 
                    }

            });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    setListAdapter(notes);

  }
```

Logcat

03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.AdapterView.getPositionForView(AdapterView.java:581)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.finished.Finished$1$1.onCheckedChanged(Finished.java:167)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.finished.Finished$1.setViewValue(Finished.java:162)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:126)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:186)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:700)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.ListView.correctTooHigh(ListView.java:1367)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:642)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3399)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2233)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-11 10:38:53.486: E/AndroidRuntime(5611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make the `SimpleCursorAdapter` a instance variable of your class. Than change setChk to the following.

```
public void setChk(View view) {
    int position = getListView().getPositionForView(view);
    Cursor c = notes.getCursor();
    if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {

        int rowid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)

        //your code
    } 
}
```

The `OnClickListener` isn't the best choice in your case. An `OnCheckedChangeListener` is  better for receiving a click on a CheckBox. It also has the advantage that you don't have to call your `fillData()` method again, which can take some time if your db is large.

**Edit:**
I modified the code of your ViewBinder to use a `OnCheckedChangeListener`:

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int nCheckedIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CHECK);
        if (columnIndex == nCheckedIndex) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;

            boolean bChecked = (cursor.getInt(nCheckedIndex) != 0);
            cb.setChecked(bChecked);

            //call if after setChecked so the listener isn't called there already
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int position = getListView().getPositionForView(buttonView);
                    Cursor c = notes.getCursor();
                    if (c.moveToPosition(position)) {

                        int rowid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)

                        if (isChecked) {
                            //TODO update db
                        } else {
                            //TODO update db                           
                        }
                    } 
                }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That worked great and I have now gotten everything to work but... like you said, OnClickListener requires me to call fillData() again. This makes the list scroll backup to the top, which is not a desired feature. I have tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and requery(). I can't get either of these to keep the list from going back to the top. Is there anything I'm missing. I'm not sure how to change to oncheckedchange because I called OnClick from xml and I can't figure out what it would take to get oncheckedchange to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I am very close to having this fully functional, but I am unable to track why the app force closes with a null pointer exception when scrolling through the list. This only happens if an item has been checked. I have posted the updated finished.java as well as the logcat. I'm sorry if it is a completely obvious mistake. I'm still very new to Java and most of my coding has been with scripting languages.

Comment: At first sight I don't see any errors. Can you try whether the buttonView or the returned ListView is null (use an if-clause to check if == null and than print result to logcat)?

Comment: For whatever reason, if I try to check anything == null I'm getting a dead code message. I kept looking through the logcat and I did notice the only 2 entries that had to do specifically with my java file were these 2. 03-11 11:50:25.826: E/AndroidRuntime(5864):  at com.finished.Finished$1$1.onCheckedChanged(Finished.java:170)
03-11 11:50:25.826: E/AndroidRuntime(5864):  at com.finished.Finished$1.setViewValue(Finished.java:163).... I did have to modify where the true and false was placed in the code you updated, but I think I placed them correctly?

Comment: Are you talking about the return true and return false? They might be wrong positioned in my code. It's sometimes a bit hard to write code here in the editor :)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the error. You have to call cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) in your setViewValue method before calling setChecked(). Otherwise setChecked will trigger the listener and buttonView is null, because it's not yet recreated, but the listener still exists. This happens at scrolling, because the rows get recycled.

Comment: I added your suggestion right below CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view; and before set checked. This does stop the application from crashing, however I now have the same problem that if you check an item, scroll until the item disappears,then scroll back up, the item is unchecked again. It does change in the database, just not in the list. I had gotten rid of the setchk method of recalling fillData(). For some reason oncheckedchanged is still not updating the list values. I'm sorry I'm asking so many questions. You have been a huge help!

Comment: Oh sorry forgot about this. You have to update the cursor. You either call fillData() again or you simply query a new cursor and call notes.changeCursor(). I'm glad that I can help you.

Comment: You are a genius!!! That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for communicating back and forth with me. I would have never gotten it myself. It wasn't near as simple as I thought it would be.